# Linker command failed with exit code 1 - cocoa pod missing foundation framework

Tags: ios, cocoapods

ok I hope I'm not butchered for this question but no solution so far I've found here is working. I've installed cocoa pods and after doing so I'm getting this error. Foundation.framework is red which I ASSUME is causing my problem. I compiled just fine before. I attempted manually linking using file inspector but it continues to fail during linking stage.

1. First of all can i assume that anything in red is what causes my linker error? Anything else might cause it?
2. Is there a way to see what it is failing to link and therefore returning the error?
3. If it is foundation.framework in the Pods project that is missing, what is the proper way to fix it?

This is driving me insane as i was very near completing and submitting my project and have been stuck on this for several days.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
xcodeproj '../PROJECT NAME.xcodeproj'
```

Any and all help and input is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be Foundation.Framework error. I have a project in XCode8 which is showing Foundation.Framework as red. But it builds just fine and also submits properly to the App Store as well.

But, just as an aside -- I have another project where I am getting a linker error for GoogleToolboxForMac and that has been driving me nuts...